# Finding the local extremum's of $(x + 2y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Finding the local extremum's of $$(x + 2y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}$$

In class the same was asked of the function $(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$. Then the first derivative was found, and the stationary points were $(0,0)$ and all the points of the $1 = x^2+y^2.$ Then to check if the points of this unit sphere in $R^2$ are points of extreme. The original function was written as $$g(t)=te^{-t}$$
where $t = x^2 + y ^2$, and it was found that for $t = 1$ that there is an extreme.

But I cannot do the same for my problem, because it is different. Thoughts?

Comment: *What* is different?  What changes when you apply the same technique to this function?

Comment: Well here you can't apply a change of variable that trivially, but you can simply find the gradient and equal it to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

computing the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ we get
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=2y^2e^{-x^2-y^2}+(x+2y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}(-2x)$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=4ye^{-x^2-y^2}+(x+2y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}(-2y)$$
and now you must set these two equations equal to Zero and compute the Solutions for $x,y$.
it is $$x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},y=0$$ or $$x=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},y=0$$ or $$x=\frac{1}{4},y=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{14}$$ or $$x=\frac{1}{4},y=-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{14}$$